# Stripe trigger event for custom customer

Tags: stripe-payments, command-line-interface

I'm trying to trigger event `invoice.payment_failed` with this stripe-cli command:

```
stripe trigger invoice.payment_failed --override invoice:customer=cus_xxxxxxxxxxx
```

but getting error

```
The customer does not have a payment method with the ID pm_1N2bxlD2ps9EQx1RcJjvzNKe. The payment method must be attached to the customer.
```

how do i override this payment method with that stripe-cli command?

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**: You need to additionally override the customer on the payment method creation and invoice item creation using:
`stripe trigger invoice.payment_failed --override payment_method:customer=cust_123 --override invoiceitem:customer=cust_123 --override invoice:customer=cust_123`

**Explanation**: Overriding parameters in complex sequences can be difficult. It helps to examine the [fixture](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/master/pkg/fixtures/triggers/invoice.payment_failed.json) (request sequence template) which backs that `trigger invoice.payment_failed` call. You can see that it:

1. Creates a customer
2. Attaches the test Payment Method `pm_card_chargeCustomerFail` to that customer
3. Creates an invoice item for that customer
4. Creates an Invoice for that customer
5. Pays the invoice using the payment method attached in 2

Since `--override invoice:customer=cus_123` sets the customer being used to create the *invoice*, you'll need the payment method to be attached for that customer, too, using `--override payment_method:customer=cus_123`.

If you overide `customer` for `invoice` and `payment_method`, the sequence will succeed, but you'll likely be confused because you'd get an `invoice.paid` and not `invoice.payment_failed`. What happened?

Looking back at the trigger fixture sequence, we have overridden the customer for payment method creation and invoice creation, but *not* for invoice item creation. What's happening is that invoice items are being creates for the unused customer still being created by the fixture, and not for the customer you provided. The invoices being created for the override customer are *empty*, with a subtotal of 0. Because these invoices do not require payment, they are [successfully `paid` without payment](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview?dashboard-or-api=api#paid):

> An invoice can transition to `paid` without an associated PaymentIntent
> succeeding if:
>
> - It has an amount_due covered by a customer’s credit balance or below the minimum charge amount

To address this, ending up with a non-zero invoice subtotal, you also must override the customer for the invoice *item* creation, using `--override invoiceitem:customer=cust_123`.

Putting it all together, you need to override the customer in three places:

`stripe trigger invoice.payment_failed --override payment_method:customer=cust_123 --override invoiceitem:customer=cust_123 --override invoice:customer=cust_123`

An alternative I should mention is creating your own custom fixture with a predefined customer or different request sequence.